# Export object with positive coordinates?

Tags: inkscape

I'm attempting to create a path in Inkscape and use those coordinates in another program where only positive (4th Quadrant) coordinates are accepted.

Is there an exportable Inkscape format that will save the coordinates of a path defined by an object, whereas all of the coordinates are positive?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the object is inside the page area (and you don't do anything funny with groups or such), all the coordinates should be positive.  You can see the coordinates when you click on a node using the path editing tool.

Of course, that may not help you much with exporting the path in a format your other program will understand.  For that, it would help to know what the program is and what kind of data it wants.

You can actually see the SVG path data by opening the saved .svg file in a text editor, or by using the *Edit → XML Editor...* tool in Inkscape.  However, the [SVG path syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) is quite complicated and somewhat cryptic, with dozens of single-letter commands used to describe paths potentially consisting of several different types of segments (straight lines, quadratic and cubic Bezier curves and elliptic arc segments, all with absolute and relative coordinate variants).  Whatever your other program is, it probably wants something simpler.